# What is the difference between a server and a mainframe?

Tags: server, semantics, cluster, mainframe

To me, it seems as though "mainframe" is a somewhat dated term; is it simply an older synonym of "server," or does it server a purpose more similar to a cluster/supercomputer?

Comment: A mainframe is a type of computer hardware.  A server is a computer dedicated to providing services.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mainframe_computer and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_(computing)

Comment: But, aren't mainframe systems generally used to provide services as well?

Comment: Naturally.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mainframe_computer#Characteristics

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A mainframe is designed for processing large amounts of information by the use of batch transaction processing. It particularly works well at running scalable software and dealing with massively parallel operations. Everything about mainframes is *screamingly fast*. Mainframes are typically built by IBM and usually run z/OS.

A server (when referred to in the hardware sense) is a PC with higher reliability / quality parts and runs usually a *NIX variant, or Windows Server.

Mainframes can run software services, such as JEE application servers, web servers, etc. They are designed to accommodate the concurrent use of hundreds or thousands of users in addition to their batch processing load.